# Where does world state store physically

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Ok, we have a commiting peers - running containers. As i assume, there is an LevelDB or CouchDB database server in containers, that stores world state. As far as i know, data must be available only from blockchain. Why can't I just connect to that database throught container and see the data or change it? If it protected, tell me, please, how protection is creating.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the CouchDB container cannot be accessed from the outside--only the attached peer is allowed to access it. Also, it can be set up with name/password login.
LevelDB does not have its own container.